# Modules naming conflict

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

Is there anyway to use exported class/function without importing a module? Consider this example:

System.ixx

```
export module System;

export class String {...};
```

System2.ixx

```
export module System2;

export class String {...};
```

Is there anyway to use it like `System::String` or `System2::String`? Obviously when I import both modules I get a compiler error.

Comment: Use `namespace`s.

Comment: @Fureeish Oh that sucks. I was hoping modules would be more like Rust's modules and eliminate need for using `namespace`.

Comment: What if there are 2 different libraries exporting identically named function?? You can't control that.

Comment: Modules would have to be unable to modify existing namespaces. That would be quite bad - imagine you have a *module* (not a header) called `<vector>` that introduces `std::vector`. Then you have a *module* called `<string>` that introduces `std::string`. Should the namespaced be abandoned (igoring backwards compatibility issues) and should they be a part of only one module now?

Comment: "*What if there are 2 different libraries exporting identically named function?*" - that's what `namespace`s are for. You would introduce a namespaec for your library in the past, you introduce it now too.

Comment: I see it isn't much different than using `#include` in this case. Thanks

Comment: In this exact case - yes. In terms of visibility, compilation strategy (and performance) and encapsulation - no, they are superior to `#include`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules change how you access code from multiple files, but that's all they do. They do not (for the most part) affect the fundamental nature of C++ as a language.

C++ already has a tool for managing name conflicts between disparate libraries and source locations: namespaces. As such, C++ modules have no need to solve a problem that has adequately already been resolved.

Comment: It might be convenient to have modules automatically namespace things, but that’s (yet one more) price paid for backward compatibility.  Fortunately it’s a pretty minor one, and we get better behavior for `using` in the bargain.

Comment: @DavisHerring: ADL makes me disagree with any mechanism that combines namespaces and modules. Granted, one could say that maybe ADL is a problem and there's a better way to solve it (or maybe you'd see a lot more `using namespace` in such a world, so you wouldn't need ADL).